# layout handle for add button to newsletter edit template in adminhtml

Tags: module, layout, adminhtml, template, newsletter

I develop module for add new button in newsletter edit template in adminhtml. And don't know which layout handle must use in my layout xml.

I try something like this but did not work:

```
<layout version="0.1.0">

    <adminhtml_newsletter_template_edit>
        <reference name="adminhtml_newsletter_template_edit">
            <block type="newslettersend/adminhtml_newsletter_template_edit" />
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_newsletter_template_edit>

</layout>
```

Comment: Did the below answer help you or is there more information you can provide to help us clarify the answer?

Comment: yes it helps. Sorry I forgot mark as useful. I just do it now. Thanks again for answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `<adminhtml_newsletter_template_edit>` you're essentially creating a new layout handle. Instead to **reference** the handle to add or remove blocks from it you would do:

```
<layout version="1.0">
    <reference name="adminhtml_newsletter_template_edit">
        <block type="newslettersend/adminhtml_newsletter_template_edit" />
    </reference>
</layout>
```

However, this probably won't work on it's own - you'll need to call either `getChildHtml` or nest it in a block type that will automatically render the children, such as `core/text_list`.

In addition, your block's layout xml doesn't seem to have a template associated, make sure the template is being set programmatically or add it to the layout.

HTH, cheers.